# MySQL Insert Slow in AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I'm trying to INSERT/UPDATE and realized it's taking about 15 seconds.

The table has only a few records (+/- 350 records) and is in an RDS instance db.t2.small

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ajustes` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tipo_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `valor` text NOT NULL,
  `array` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-01-01 00:00:00',
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-01-01 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tipo_id` (`tipo_id`),
  KEY `nome` (`nome`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=351 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I do not even know where to begin with.
I tried to use REPAIR but see the error:

> The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair

Comment: What else is the RDS doing - is this the *only* table? What do the CloudWatch stats for CPU etc. look like for the server?

Comment: all tables are slow.
the cpu appears to be normal, operating at 8%

Comment: update took 0.267ms local vs 6.244ms in production.
should I change innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0 ?

Comment: OK, hang on. You say 15 seconds in your question, but 0.006 seconds in your comment. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, in Brazil we use the dot as a decimal separator. In the last test in another table it consumed 6 seconds. But a unique query. In my question it took 15 because it had other querys running sequentially ..

Comment: OK, that's still not making sense - MySQL would have said "267ms", not "0,267ms", even if it's localizing the decimal separator. If you trigger a simple update to this simple table, you're literally sitting able to count out multiple seconds before the response comes back? Even a quarter second is an eternity for how small and simple this table apparently is.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled two parameters and it works:

```
sync-binlog = 0 
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```